# render excel data to web page row by row (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webmatrix

Can someone help me print data row by row using WebMatrix 2

i am trying to use excel 2007 and/or 2003 the last line DataGrid1 is not working. this is my third day trying, please help.

```
String Excel = "C://TEST/test_2.xls";
String sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Excel +";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

string.System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection objConn = new`system.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);`


objConn.Open();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", objConn);

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(objCmdSelect);

System.Data.DataSet objDataset1 = new System.Data.DataSet();

objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData");
objConn.Close();
int c = objDataset1.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
int count =0;

//For Test
Response.Write("Colums: "+objDataset1.Tables[0].Columns.Count.ToString()+"<br>");
Response.Write("Rows: "+objDataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString()+"<br>");


// Bind data to DataGrid control. Following part not working, also i like to print data with for or foreach loop)

DataGrid1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
//Other option if Data.Grid does not work!!
change Rows to Columns to print Columns.
for (int i=0;i<r;i++){
for (int j=0;j<c;j++){
Response.Write(objDataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j]+" ");
}
Response.Write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: How is it not working?  What is the error?

Comment: Clean up your code a bit.. it's hard to tell what you are trying to use and what you are not wanting to use via the comments. Also add the following to the uses section at the top of the page and you won't have to fully qualify the objCmdSelect 
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
It's a bit messy in regards to readability

Comment: @{using System.Data; and using system.Data.OleDb is giving two syntex errors. i don't have Visual studio, so i am using WebMatrix.

Comment: You are better advised to use Visual Studio Express for Web if you are developing Web Forms and you don't have Visual Studio. It is free: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web

Answer (score 1):

Well aside from the various syntax errors in your code, you've created a new `OleDbDataAdapter` but not attached it to anything. I suspect that your program is throwing an exception during the `Fill` statement because it doesn't have an SQL command to execute. You need to edit your instantiation of the `OleDataDbAdapter` object to:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(objCmdSelect);
```

Also, as DJ KRAZE correctly pointed out, adding the following lines to the top of your code will help you clean things up a bit and make it a little easier to understand:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

I'm not sure what your comment about "printing" data with a loop means, but binding the data to the `DataGrid` means you don't have to.

**EDIT:**

Here's how you can improve your loop

```
foreach(DataRow row in objDataset1.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach(DataColumn col in objDataset1.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        Response.Write(row[col.ColumnName].ToString());
    }

    Response.Write(count++ + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Following the current error and that's the reason i want to use loop to read dataset line by line. FYI i just updated the code in the top block. CS0103: The name 'DataGrid1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in objDataset1.Tables[0].Rows){ Response.Write(row.ToString() + count++ +"<br>");} and the output is following System.Data.DataRow1
System.Data.DataRow2
System.Data.DataRow3
..................
System.Data.DataRow28

Comment: @AnupSingh For your loop, you need to index each of the row items (i.e. column names) thus: `Response.Write(row["column name"].ToString())`. If there are a limited number of columns and you know the names then you can write a statement for each, otherwise just loop along them: `foreach(DataColumn col in objDataset1.Tables[0].Columns` and then `Response.Write(row[col.ColumnName].ToString()`